# DNN LDAP Authentication with DNN.ActiveDirectory

Tags: ldap, dotnetnuke

I am having some trouble and need some help. I am trying to connect a website to authenticate to Active Directory through LDAP using DNN.ActiveDirectory, but I can only get the "Check Root Domain" portion to pass. Using ldp.exe on the server I am able to connect to the domain controller and query the users on it with the same user name and password I am trying to use with the plugin, and even using my domain admin account makes no difference. I have tried it with every authentication type, changing the root domain (only way that would get the check root domain to pass is the LDAP://domain.local), with/without the domain in front of the username, and with/without the default domain filled out.

I don't have access to the error logs at the moment since I am not at that office yet, so I will get those posted when I can. If I remember correctly the error being logged was an authentication error. LDAP initially wasn't configured on the domain controller so I had to set that up, and admittedly I am not too familiar with it so I followed this guide: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-ldaps-on-windows-server/ba-p/385362. I am using the default ports. I stopped before setting up LDAPS, but when I couldn't get that to work I continued through up to the signing the certificate part. I was working on getting the certificate signed when I came across notes that DNN.ActiveDirectory doesn't support LDAPS. My tests with successful connections using ldp.exe were all against port 389. Are there some extra configurations that are needed to get DNN.ActiveDirectory working that weren't covered in that guide, or any common snags I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNN.ActiveDirectory has not been maintained for a while, and does not support LDAPS afaik - see [Checking Root Domain step fails](https://github.com/DNNCommunity/DNN.ActiveDirectory/issues/73).

My recommendation is to have a look at [AD-Pro Authentication](https://www.glantonmodules.com/ad-pro-authentication).